# Populate combobox with attributes of xml element

Tags: xml, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have the following XML

```
<device id="DI-1561">
    <model>LG-F320L</model>
    <series>LG B2</series>
    <os>4.4.2</os>
    <location>Unk</location>
</device>
<device id="DI-1572">
    <model>SM-G900H</model>
    <series>GS5</series>
    <os>4.4.2</os>
    <location>Unk</location>
</device>
```

On loading userform1, I want combobox1 to populate with all of the "id" attributes from  element. I have the following code to populate it based on the content of a given element, but that isn't what I need in this case. Thanks.

```
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("path to xml")
    Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = (From element In doc.Descendants("model") Select element.Value).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Me.ComboBox1.DataSource =
  (From element In doc.Root.Elements("device")
   Select element.Attribute("id").Value).ToList()
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution and am getting 'Root' is not a member of 'Xml'.  Am I missing an import statement?

Comment: nm, switched xml.Root.Elements("device") to doc.Root.Elements("device") which makes sense.  Great solution!

Comment: @thetimmer: `xml` was my local variable. Yes, it should be `doc` to work in OP's code. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

More generalized and similar to your solution would be something like this:

```
     Me.ComboBox1.DataSource =(from element in doc.Descendants("device") 
                               select element.Attribute("id").Value).ToList();
```